# Primeng Theme change

Tags: primeng, angular10

Can I use primeNg 5 omega theme with in my project (which I upgraded from angular 5 to 10) by storing the theme folder inside my assets(my primeng version will remain 10)?

Answer (score 1):

Omega theme has been deprecated since primeng 6 at that version primeng interduce new theme set called *nova* and *luna*.

primeng version 10  the team interduce a new design sets *bootstrap , material design , material design compact , fluent and primeone* ,this update was a complete theme changes like a new guide and internal class changes so any custom theme you just did will not work until you make some changes(most of the time just class change ).

all primeng free themes are css files so changing the theme will required overwrite the main component classes.

in one of our project we almost change most main classes, otherwise you will have to buy a premium primeng theme or get a primeng designer license this will provide some benefit to the primeng teem and you will get a theme base of scss files the will give you a lot of variable so you can tweak the design as you wish.